# Required parameters match given parameters, yet, still cannot call the method?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics, parameters

I wrote a method called `sort()`, in which the goal is to sort any array based on the minimum index (determined by an override of the `compareTo()` method within the individual objects' classes). This method relies on another method called `minIndex()` in which the goal is return the minimum index of the array. However, whenever I call `minIndex()` from `sort()`, I get this error:

`The method minIndex(E[], int) in the type Lab11_2 is not applicable for the arguments (E[], int)`

Here is `sort()`:

```
// Sorts any array by the order of the minimum index.
public static <E> E[] sort(E[] arr){

    int minInd;
    E tempObj;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            
        minInd = minIndex(arr, i); // Get the minimum index of the array.

        // Swap the object with the minimum index with the object at index 'i'.
        tempObj = arr[minInd];
        arr[minInd] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tempObj;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Here is `minIndex()`:

```
// Returns the minimum index of an array.
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int minIndex(E[] arr, int start){

    int ind = start;
    for(int k = start + 1; k < arr.length; k++){

        if(arr[k].compareTo(arr[ind]) < 0){
            ind = k;
        }
    }

    return ind;
}
```

So, how do I make the call successfully? Because, to me, the parameters that are required by `minIndex()` and the parameters that are given by `sort()` look exactly the same: `E[], int`. I am new whenever it comes to generics and non-primitive data types, so it is a bit confusing. As a warning, there may be runtime errors in the code that I do not know about yet, as I have not had a chance to compile it and actually test it, since it is giving me this error.

Comment: Maybe there are other issues in your code that causes the compiler to give you such a confusing message, but at least, `E` in your `sort` is missing the `extends Comparable<E>` constraint that `E` in `minIndex` has.

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah, I just figured that out about five minutes ago, lol. But, it works now, so I will respond to this post with the answer.

Comment: why don't you just use Comparable like so `public static int minIndex(Comparable[] arr, int start)`, same in `sort`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, I found the answer shortly after making this post. The solution was to change the `sort()` definition from (and as @Sweeper mentioned):

```
public static <E> E[] sort(E[] arr)
```

to:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E[] sort(E[] arr)
```

Why does this work? Well, to be honest, my lack of expertise disallows me to know the answer. However, if someone else *does* know why this works, please edit this response to include the answer, or post it in the comment section of this response. Because I would like to know why it works as well.